# disabling comments causing display issues in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

http://www.handheldtesting.com/

When either checking "disable comments" in the back end, or adding **'display:none:'**

```
<div id="respond" class="comment-respond" style="display:none;">
```

in the code.

1/2 of the content on the page disappears, as the footer moves up.

Any ideas?

Thanks so much,
Ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of CSS seems to be causing the problem:

```
body.responsive.layout-full #page-wrapper .full-container {
  height: 172px;
}
```

I'm not sure why that height is explicitly set, seems odd.  You should probably test the affects before totally deleting it...